# Ошибка при установке Μaven

Tags: java

Ребята, помогите что не так. Устанавливаю Μaven.

Скачал архив, распаковал и положил на диск С:\Tools
Cоздал новую переменную среды  M2_HOME=c:\Tools\apache-maven-3.5.2
Добавил эту переменную в Path : %M2_HOME%\bin
Открываю командную строку и делаю проверку:
echo %PATH%
echo %M2_HOME%
mvn –version
Последняя команда выдает ошибку. Что я сделал не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй перезагрузи комп.

Comment: в PATH который добавили? Тот что в переменных среды пользователя или системный? Нужно в системные параметры добавлять.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в том, что я не правильно распаковал Maven, тоесть на диске С он был в двух папках с одинаковым названием c:\Tools\apache-maven-3.5.2\apache-maven-3.5.2. А в переменной среды я прописал только одну папку M2_HOME=c:\Tools\apache-maven-3.5.2 Удалил лишнее и все заработало.

Comment: А как надо правильно было сделать?

Comment: Да, будет круто, если вы расскажете немного подробнее о том, как решили проблему - это может быть полезно будущим посетителям вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

нужно в переменную окружения Path прописать путь к мавену (включая bin каталог)